# Fragment not loaded in Android < 6.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am replacing my Fragments with this:

```
   @Override
   public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment newFragment = null;
        String tag = "";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                newFragment = new MyFragment();
                tag = "termine";
                break;
            case 1:
                newFragment = new MyMapFragment();
                tag = "map";
                break;
            case 2:
                newFragment = new SearchFragment();
                tag = "search";
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                newFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                tag = "settings";
                break;
            case 5:
                newFragment = new AboutFragment();
                tag = "about";
                break;
        }

        if (newFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, newFragment, tag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

My gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
//    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.coolapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.3.0'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'
    compile 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:+'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.myapp.coolapp.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return view;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        if (position != 3) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
        List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.nav_title1)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.nav_title2)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.nav_title3)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(""));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.nav_title4)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getResources().getString(R.string.nav_title5)));
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     * @param toolbar      The Toolbar of the activity.
     */
    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

On devices with Android 6.0 it works perfect, everything is the way it should be but on devices < 6.0 the app also starts without problems but the content of the fragment isn't replaced.
So this is for all fragments so I don't think it is the fragment layout's problem.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: you are using the standard Navigation Drawer to implement your solution?

Comment: Sorry, No I'm using a custom one. I edited my answer and added it...

Comment: something is deprecated in android, or your activity_main.xml must be very misconfigured.

Comment: Without throwing this code into an actual project, I see nothing wrong with it. Perhaps, you could make a [mcve]?